# Adding the App Store link to the Admob account is necessary?

Tags: android, admob

I have a question that I have already published my new Android app in Play Store 1 month ago.
My question is that is it necessary to add the Play Store link to my Admob account or I can use without adding the same?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add more information to the question. E.g. the purpose of the link you want to add or not. Why you think you should or shouldn't add the link.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this link - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10417515

All new apps linked to supported app stores after **May 2021** will need to be reviewed and approved. Ad serving will be **limited until review is completed** and the app is approved.

Note that new apps must be listed and linked to a supported store in order to be approved and remove the ad serving limit. New apps not listed to any supported stores won't be able to be reviewed. To have an app reviewed and eligible for approval, list and link the app to a supported store.

**This new process will be rolled out gradually during 2021.**

All monetizing apps will eventually need to be listed and linked to a supported app store. We recommend linking your apps as soon as they're listed and then submitting for review to avoid interruptions in monetization.